# Non legacy code in generics gives compiler warning which shouldn't be. Kindly clear it

Tags: java, generics, collections, compiler-warnings

I was working in a example where it test the legacy and non legacy of the code.  Here's a example took from SCJP by Kathy/bates.  I read these things from that book and trying to workout the same in my system.  It was running fine as mentioned in the book.  But for both examples i tried the compiler generated the warning mentioned below.  But when we are running the non legacy code it shouldn't warn us.  I don't know whether there was a bug in book's example are something i was doing is error.  Please clear me.  Thanks in Advance !  Below i attached the screen shot from book for reference.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestBadLegacy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List < Integer > myList = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        myList.add(4);
        myList.add(6);
        Inserter in = new Inserter(); in .insert(myList); // pass List<Integer> to legacy code
    }
}
class Inserter {
    // method with a non-generic List argument
    void insert(List list) {
        list.add(new Integer(42)); // adds to the incoming list
    }
}
```

Sure, this code works.It compiles, and it runs.The insert() method puts an
Integer into the list that was originally typed as `<Integer>` , so no problem.
But… what if we modify the `insert()` method like this:

```
void insert(List list) {
    list.add(new String("42")); // put a String in the list 
    // passed in
}
```

- Page No: 603, 3rd Paragraph

  When you called the addAll()method in the earlier example, it didn't insert
  anything to the list (it simply added up the values within the collection), so there
  was no risk to the caller that his list would be modified in some horrible way. It
  compiled and ran just fine. But in the second version, with the legacy insert()
  method that adds a String, the compiler generated a warning:

It runs fine in both case and in both cases i am getting same ***Warning:***, which shouldn't be.

> Note: TestBadLegacy.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

[image: SCJP BOOK Pg. No 602]
[image: SCJP Book Pg. No 603]

Comment: Where's the code that generates a warning and shouldn't, according to you?

Comment: Why do you say there should be no warnings?

Comment: "When you called the addAll()method in the earlier example"...where is this `addAll()` method?

Comment: "But in the second version, with the legacy insert() method that adds a String, the compiler generated a warning:" Kathy says that the code *should* give a warning.

Comment: Which java compiler are you using?  1.6 gives a warning about raw types for both examples.

Comment: No `addAll()` comes in previous example.  Here they are just mentioning that.  But when we run the first set of code with adds Integer(40) it shouldn't generate warnings.  And the code adds String(40) should generate warnings.  This was my doubt is?

Comment: @MonadNewb: Yes.  I am getting warning for both the versions.  I am using version 1.7 of Java.

Comment: You simply misread the words of the author. A warning is issued as soon as you do an unchecked or unsafe operation. If the compiler was able to differentiate between the String addition and the Integer addition, it would not be an unsafe or unchecked operation anymore, and it would compile one and refuse to compile the other. It's not able to say if adding whatever to the list is safe, so it issues a warning.

Comment: You *should* get a warning because you are performing an unsafe action. The author clearly states that this is the correct behavior when you mix generics with legacy code as in this example.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thank you very much for your kind reply.  I gone through those two pages and i got what i misread.  The method in Inserter class should be like this. `void insert(List<Integer> list)`.  So it will not generate warnings while compiling.  In legacy it can accept of any type of primitive objects.  So it is throwing that warning.  Please let me know i understood correct or not?

Comment: You got it. A raw list (List, without generic type information) accepts any kind of object. Since the compiler can't ensure that what you add to the listy conforms to its original, typed declaration, it issues a warning. "primitive object" doesn't mean anything, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it doesn't matter what the type of the argument to `add()` is in `insert()` -- calling it with *any* argument will get you this warning.  The warning is at the call to `add()` itself, and the compiler does *not* do an extended dataflow analysis through both methods. You're making the compiler out to be much smarter than it is.

Comment: Can you please brief.  I am unable to understand.

Comment: @JavaBeginer: can you please take more time to read and try to understand the answers. You already misread the author of the book. Try not to misread the answers and comments here. Take time to carefully read them.

Comment: You're telling the compiler to add a String/Integer to a list.  The compiler has an untyped list and does NOT know if that will work or not, since it could be a list of lists, or a list of custom objects, etc.

Comment: Ok let me go through again and try to get things.

Comment: Thankyou for your nice answer which i understood just now.